# Push Notification - didReceiveRemoteNotification not being called on IOS 16.6.1

Tags: swift, firebase, notifications, push, messaging

I'm building a simple application (Simple chat application) which needs to update the badge number when you receives a push notification from Firebase.

The problem is that the "didReceiveRemoteNotification" is supposed to be called when it is on background. but it does not.

And Yes! Iphone and Ipad could receive the notification when its in background,
And Yes! "didReceiveRemoteNotification" did get called when the application is on foreground
And Yes! The data "userInfo" received is correct.
And Yes! Using the firebase console, I'm able to receive the notification.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) { self.updateNotificationBadge(application: application, userInfo: userInfo)
    }

private func updateNotificationBadge(application: UIApplication, userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]){ let notificationType = userInfo["notificationType"] as? String print("\(notificationType) APN recieved: \(userInfo)") print(userInfo)

let state = application.applicationState

let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard var badgeCount = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "badgeCount") if badgeCount > 0 { badgeCount += 1 else { badgeCount = 1
        } userDefaults.set(badgeCount, forKey: "badgeCount")
    }
```

I have searched numerous solutions on Stack-overflow but none of them works. Maybe I'm missing something.

This is what i tried and didn't work:

1. When the user send a push notification:

> func sendPushNotification(token: String, title: String, body: String, notificationType: ATCNotificationType, payload: [String: String]) {

```
var data = payload data["notificationType"] = notificationType.rawValue let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : token,
                                           "content-available": 1,
                                           "priority":"high",
                                           "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body, "sound": "default"],
                                           "aps":["content-available":1,
                                                  "apns-priority":5,
                                                  "apns-push-type":"background",
                                                  "badge":0],
                                           "data" : data
        ] handlePushNotification(with: paramString)
    }
```

2. Make sure the Capabilities are on:
   [image]

[image]

3. Try both but almost similar functions to receive Push notification:

   private func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) { self.updateNotificationBadge(application: application, userInfo: userInfo)
   }

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) { self.updateNotificationBadge(application: application, userInfo: userInfo)
   }
4. Make sure that the app is NOT terminated.

Comment: Is the app terminated or in the background? If it's terminated it won't receive the push. If its in the background but the battery is low it won't receive the push neither

Comment: Yes. it does make sense. but ok. Now, on my next attempt, I made sure that the app is not being terminated and tried again. Unfortunately it is still not getting called.